# Postgresql array retrieved via array_to_json needs conversion back into array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I am saving an array of objects in postgresql.
In postgresql the field of type text[] looks like the following:

```
{{'x':'80','y':'60'},{'x':'750','y':'590'}}
```

The above represents an array of 2 objects.

On the server, I am retrieving this field by using array_to_json
Once I use this function to retrieve the values I get the following array

```
arr = [["'x':'80'","'y':'60'"],["'x':'750'","'y':'590'"]]
```

I want to convert it back into an array of objects like the following

```
[{x:80,y:60},{x:750,y:590}]
```

How can I do this

Comment: Please show what steps you have already tried.

Comment: Well, quick and dirty would be: `obj=eval("({"+arr.join(",")+"})")`.

Comment: Don't store JSON as text, use json or rather jsonb type instead.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann for your comment. Can you please explain why it works?

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for that comment. I will try that. I think you are implying that then I will not have do any string parsing?

Comment: That depends on how you're going to use the results, everything you get from postgresql is string by default. Beacuse you've tagged this with JavaScript, I assume the problem occurs in a Node.js script. If that's the case, you can convert a jsonb type to the corresponding JS type with JSON.parse.

Comment: [jsonb documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-json.html) is worth of reading before you start to convert the types. I hope you haven't stored a lot of data yet.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks. I am still in the development phase and hence I am not concerned about data loss. Incidentally based on your suggestion I changed over to json data type (only so that I could view the data in the database) and happily the conversions are no longer required except that the numeric values returned by postgresql are strings and I had to make minor adjustment in my code for that. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
arr = ["'x':'80'", "'y':'60'"];
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [key, value] = curr.split(":");
  acc[key.match(/\w+/)[0]] = value.match(/\w+/)[0];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```